# Sum of all numbers from a range returns always 0

Tags: javascript

I have the following code. I want to introduce from the keyboard the range but the result of the sum it is always 0 and i do not understand what it is wrong.

```
let first = Number(prompt("Please insert the first number: "));
let last = Number(prompt("Please insert the last number: "));

function addition(first, last) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        sum += i;
    }
    console.log("Sum is: ", sum);
}

addition();
```

Thank you!

Comment: You don't pass the parameters to the function.

Comment: `addition();` should be `addition(first, last);` because your function expects two arguments:  `function addition(first, last) {` or use the outer scope variables like: `function addition() {` (no arguments at all) since the names are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function parameters are shadowing your local variables:

```
for (let i = first; i <= last; i++) {
```

refers to the function parameters here:

```
function addition(first, last) {
```

but you don't pass any parameters:

```
addition();
```

You can do `addition(first, last);` or remove the parameters altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not passing the parameters to `addition`, so do the following:

```
let first = Number(prompt("Please insert the first number: "));
let last = Number(prompt("Please insert the last number: "));

function addition(first, last) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = first; i <= last; i++) {
    sum += i;
  }
  console.log("Sum is: ", sum);
}

addition(first, last);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing your arguments in the function call and need to pass said arguments(first and last) to the function, during the call, as follows

```
addition(first, last);
```

This should allow the function to work as exoected.

The reason for this is that your function definition

```
function addition(first, last) { }
```

requires 2 parameters to be passed to the function, which you were not providing.